# The existence and value of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I am doing the following homework:

> Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|\neq1$. Prove that the integral:
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}dx$$
>
> exists and compute its value.

But I only determined the value of the integral (using complex analysis). Is that enough to show the existence of the integral? Actually this is obvious, but I want to be sure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious, why are you not allowing $a=0$?

Comment: Edited it, thanks :-)

Comment: Have you tried considering real part of the geometric series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a^{n}e^{inx}$ and $\sum_{n\geq0}(\frac{1}{a})^{n}e^{inx}$ for $|a| \neq 1$ ? I think that the sums and the integral can be interchanged under these assumtions

Comment: I just want to know if computing the value of the integral is sufficient for the first part, i.e. showing that the integral exists. I am just curious why the task is divided into two parts, since the first follows from the second.

Comment: Well i think it depends on how you calculated the integral. Usually when we compute integrals with residue theorem and so, we are actually computing a principle value of the integral, since we are taking "symmetric limits". However if you prove that the integral exists and converges absolutely, then the principal value must coincide with the "original" one, so then it suffices to compute the weaker version (principal value) to determine the value of the integral

Comment: What do you mean with principal value and symmetric limits?

Comment: See for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value